# cat wc -l count lines line with defined line endings (e.g Mac OS X specific)

Tags: macos, bash, unix, cat

As any command-line user I sometimes want to count lines in text file with well known command:

```
cat some_text_file | wc -l
```

I face the problem on Mac OS X, which as far I have it studied is connected with different line endings (sometimes I have output from Mac OS X version of Excel which uses OS X specific line ending, which is not understandable for wc -l; After changin line endings to UNIX style e.g in SublimeText everything works as expected).

SO MY QUESTION:

Can I pass somehow to `wc -l` the line ending kind as somee parameter which should be used? If yes please provide some example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
cat some_text_file | tr "\r" "\n" | wc -l
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
strings some_text_file | wc -l
```

Comment: What? This has nothing to do with what the question asked for.

Comment: STRINGS(1)                                                          STRINGS(1)

NAME
       strings - find the printable strings in a object, or other binary, file

Comment: (1) My comment may have been unnecessarily harsh; I apologize for that. However, (2) the question is about text files. As the quote from the man page you posted implies, there’s little point in running `strings` on text files – it’s meant for finding text in binary files. (3) `echo -e "To\nbe\nor\nnot\nto\nbe;\nthat\nis\nthe\nquestion."` clearly produces 10 lines, but if you pipe it into `strings | wc -l`, it says 2. Conversely, `echo "The quïck bröwn fox jûmps över thé lazy dog."` produces one line, but `strings | wc -l` says 6. So your suggestion yields incorrect results. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (4) The best that your answer could be is a more resource-expensive, complicated variant on `cat some_text_file | wc -l`, which, in turn, is a more resource-expensive, complicated variation on `wc -l < some_text_file`. None of these approaches addresses the part of the question that makes it somewhat distinctive – the fact that it’s asking about files that might end with Unix-style line endings and might end with CR+LF. What part of your answer do you think tells `wc -l` the kind of line ending that should be used?

Comment: Had I a file of the sort in question (it's unclear exactly what file format it is), I'd have tried my suggestion myself, before suggesting it.  It's a quick and dirty method that occasionally works for me; it may have worked for him, or others with similar, non-specific mixed file parsing issues who happen upon this thread.